# Storing Uploaded Files in Azure Web Sites: File System or Azure Storage

Tags: azure-storage, azure-web-app-service

When using Azure Web Sites (WAWS) general opinion seems to be that uploaded content such as photo's or files should be stored in Azure Storage Blobs and not in the WAWS File System.

Clearly using Azure Storage is a great idea if you have a lot of data and need scale and redundancy however for small or simple sites it seems to add another layer of complexity and also means you can't easily use things like ImageResizer without purchasing the Azure compatible licence etc.

So given that products like WordPress from the Azure Gallery uses "/site/wwwroot/wp-content/uploads/" to store all uploaded files on WAWS is there anything wrong with using the WAWS file system for storage or are there other considerations to take into account when using Azure WAWS?

Answer (score 3):

The major drawback to using the WAWS storage is that your data is now intermingled with the application. By saving all of your plugins/images/blobs externally in a database or blob storage, you retain the flexibility to redeploy your application to a new region/datacenter by just pushing your code to the new website and changing connection strings.

If your plugins/images are stored on disk in WAWS, then you need to make sure that you are backing it up appropriately. If anything happens, you need to restore the site along with all of the data that had been uploaded.

Answer (score 2):

Azure Web Sites is using Azure storage as a file storage so essentially the level of complexity you're talking about is abstracted.
Another great benefit that comes with this approach is if you scale your web site to multiple instances all of them will work with exact same file content.

Of course if you want to use pure Azure Storage features like snapshots or sharing specific content to specific users this is not available as is. But for the web site purposes is quite good.

Hope that helps

Comment: This question was answered some years ago. It still the same with Azure Web Apps?